# Is there a way to lock the Netflix profile in a rooted Galaxy Tab 3 Lite (SM-T110)?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, netflix, samsung-galaxy-tab-3-lite

I would like to lock account switching in Netflix. I found that you can do this with a restricted profile but this version of android doesn't have that feature. I can create new accounts with a terminal, but this does not enable the "Users" option in the settings menu.

Is there another way to lock the account switching, or is this impossible?

Android version: 4.2.2